# Progress bar in updatedb

Tags: locate

Is it possible to get a reliable progress bar (or just a reliable information how long it will take) when doing `updatedb`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no such option, as well it shouldn't have any.

If you need to measure that, you must first know how many files are present on your system, that means loop through everything twice, it can be slow

One evicent example is that if you extract kernel source code with `file-roller`, it's slower than doing the same thing with `tar` directly, because file-roller need to file out all files first(otherwise the progress bar might be incorrectly displayed), and you wait for a while before extraction process actually began.

Comment: You are totally right. However, it would be possible to predict the time for the next run using a “smart guess”. For instance one could compute an exponentially weighted moving average from the past values, which basically assumes that the next run will take as long as the average of the last runs. This is of course not exact, but very cheap to compute since it doesn't loop over the file system. Given that neither the amount of files nor the load changes dramatically it will yield to very practical estimated values.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an efficient solution, but is not as bad as looping through everything twice.

Number of files processed by `updatedb` is equal to:

```
updatedb -v | wc -l
```

or roughly equal to:

```
find / -mount | wc -l
```

We cannot use these commands to get the number, because it would be looping twice.

But we can use the number of used inodes, which is approximately the same:

```
df -i | grep '/$' | awk '{print $3}'
```

Having this value, we can calculate how far we got while `updatedb -v` command is running:

```
count=$(df -i | grep '/$' | awk '{print $3}')

sudo updatedb -v | while read
do
    printf "%3d\r" $((100 * (++i) / count))
done
```

This is very inefficient, because `printf` is called for every line in the output of `updatedb -v`. Better if we `printf` for only some of the lines.

```
count=$(df -i | grep '/$' | awk '{print $3}')

sudo updatedb -v | while read
do
    if (( ++i % (count/20) == 0 )); then
        printf "%3d\r" $((100 * i / count))
    fi
done
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But my `df -i` reports 0 in all columns for /. Maybe extracting the current database's file count from `locate -S` (or `--statistics` or other similar switch your `locate` implementation has) could also be used as an approximative file count.

Comment: This solution worked for me, the percentage value seemed quite precise.

Comment: `updatedb` does not have `-v` option anymore [since `19.10`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183518/updatedb-command-line-options-changed-during-upgrade-from-19-04-to-19-10), dunno if there are alternatives...